# How to remove last draw UIBezierPath from view?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I am drawing the line on touch using "UIBezierPath" UIBezierPath.

I want to implement the UNDO feature in which when user press on UNDO button then last drawn line should be removed from the screen.

How can i do this? I have used "removeAllPoints" function of "UIBezierPath" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Take all the paths in an array and then undo functionality with [yourPathArray removeLastObject]; and call [yourPathClass setNeedsDisplay]

Comment: if i call [yourPathClass setNeedsDisplay] then drawRect method is called so i need to redraw all path in drawRect after removing the last one?

Comment: Obviously.. this will help you if you are going to make like RoofSnap App

Comment: can u pls explain? i m not getting

Comment: Once have a look at this app https://itunes.apple.com/lk/app/roofsnap-sketch/id500013182?mt=8 then you will get to know what i am trying to explain

Comment: It all depends upon how you're doing this. I'm going to guess that you are just calling `addLineToPoint` on your existing `UIBezierPath` every time you add a new line segment? If so, you might have to contemplate a different model, one where you maintain your own `NSMutableArray` of points that you are going to draw lines between and then rebuild the `UIBezierPath` each time. But this way, the process of removing a line segment is easy as removing an entry from the mutable array and the rebuild the `UIBezierPath` again.